# Extremely slow ffmpeg/sws_scale() - only on heavy duty

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, ffmpeg

I am writing a video player using ffmpeg (Windows only, Visual Studio 2015, 64 bit compile).
With common videos (up to 4K @ 30FPS), it works pretty good. But with my maximum target - 4K @ 60FPS, it fails. Decoding still is fast enough, but when it comes to YUV/BGRA conversion it is simply not fast enough, even though it's done in 16 threads (one thread per frame on a 16/32 core machine).

So as a first countermeasure I skipped the conversion of some frames and got a stable frame rate of ~40 that way. Comparing the two versions in Concurrency Visualizer, I found a strange issue I don't know the reason of.

.

Here's an image of the frameskip version:
[image]
You see that the conversion is pretty quick (average roughly ~35ms)
Thus, as multiple threads are used, it also should be quick enough for 60FPS, but it isn't!

.

The image of the non-frameskip version shows why:
[image]
The conversion of a single frame has become ten times slower than before (average roughly ~350ms). Now a heavy workload on many cores would of course cause a minor slowdown per core due to reduced turbo - let's say 10 or 20%. But never an extreme slowdown of ~1000%.

.

Interesting detail is, that the stack trace of the non-frameskip version shows some system activity I don't really understand - beginning with `ntoskrnl.exe!KiPageFault+0x373`. There are no exceptions, other error messages or such - it just becomes extremely slow.

Edit: A colleague just told me that this looks like a memory problem with paged-out memory at first glance - but my memory utilization is low (below 1GB, and more than 20GB free)

Can anyone tell me what could be causing this?

Comment: It's calling `yuv2rgb_c`, a C function. That is probably the reason of the slowdown. Other than the framerate, is there another difference between your 4k30 and 4k60 ffmpeg invocations? Possibly one being 10 bits/component and the other being 8 bits/component, or something like that? Or one scaling to RGB and the other not?

Comment: No, it's both the same movie... both times `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P` as source and bgra as target, no scaling, just converting.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too old to be useful, but just for the record:

What's probably happening is that you're allocating 4k frames over and over again in multiple threads. The windows allocator really doesn't like that access pattern.

The malloc itself will not show up in the profiler, since only when the memory is actually accessed, will the OS fetch the pages. This shows up as `ntoskrnl.exe!KiPageFault` and gets attributed to the function first accessing the new memory.

Solutions include:

- Using a different allocator (e.g. tbb_malloc, mimalloc, etc.)
- Using your own per-thread or per process frame pool. ffmpeg does something similar internally, maybe you can just use [that](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/56ff01e6ec915963b467d3d2d488e400f67f46a3/libavutil/buffer.h#L220-L247).